# To display same content in a webpage as user input in textarea of blog section

Tags: php, html

To display content in my php webpage as same as user input in my blog page including paragraph, link, code in exact same manner as they input in my blog section

Comment: Hola, you may want to reference the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. As it is, your question is rather unclear.

Comment: @ashkay Your question is not clear at all, please add some code and address the issue so people can help you, I'm sorry that you got downvoted on your first question I'm personally against this, but there are people who have to help keep the website useful for everyone, hope you can edit your question and get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you get the value use `$a= nl2br($_POST['textareaname']);`
this will save your line breaks everytime the user hits enter `echo $a;`

if you want more formatting option have a look at javascript tinyMce Textarea plugin